# How do you show Xcode's build log? (Trying to verify if iPhone distribution build zip was created correctly.)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm trying to zip up my iPhone application for App Store distribution.

The distribution instructions suggest looking in the build log to check if the mobileprovision file was included, but I can't figure out how to show a build log.

> **Apple's instructions:**
>
> To confirm your build was successful, check for the following:
>
> > Open the Build Log detail view and confirm the presence of the "embedded.mobileprovision” file. This will take you to the line in the build log that shows the provisioning profile was successfully called.

Comment: For xcode 5: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19014359/476716

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

i have highlighted what you need to change. select "All messages" instead of "Issues Only" and the follow the screenshots below.

Answer (score 7):

When you have the Build Results window showing, right-click on any item and select "Open These Latest Results as Transcript Text File".

Comment: Or `right-click` on any item and choose `Expand All Transcripts`.

Answer (score 6):

Command-Shift-B to show the Build Results window.  Click on a specific item in the results window to see the command line that actually executed.

Answer (score 4):

In IOS sdk 4+ in order to see the actual full log output it seems you have to go

Navigators->log

(pops up log navigator)

select the log in question (double click it)

then control click on the list of "messages" and select "expand all transcripts" from the context menu

Answer (score 3):

At the bottom left of the build window (the one that gives the summary of the build) there are 4 icons.

- A tick
- Yellow triange
- a few lines
- Downward triangle

The first 3 toggle information. The third is the one you want it will open a full build log.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the build results window.(the one that shows up with errors and whatnot)  At the bottom of the window it should list all the commands that it used to build the app.  You might also need to modify the project settings and the build settings to get what you want.  Plus make sure you are building using the right build configuration (that gets me sometimes ).