# XCode4 cannot include head file in <>

Tags: c++, ios, xcode4

i'm building https://github.com/dev2dev/OpenSceneGraph-port-to-IOS , it depends on freetype ,so  we need " #include  " in some files.
I always get the build error : ***'ft2build.h' not found***.

have tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/2109083 ,but didnt work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you installed the `freetype` package?  If not, and you have [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/), you can install with `sudo port install freetype`.  `ft2build.h` will then be located at `/opt/local/include/ft2build.h`.

You will need to follow the instructions on the StackOverflow question you mentioned on how to add `/opt/local/include` to the User Header Search Paths in Xcode.

Comment: Actually what a stupid misstake i had made! OSGIphone xcode project has many targets, i forgot change the target to osgdb_freetype which need to set the "User Header Path".No need to install freetype. Sorry, i'm new to XCode and ios dev :)