# Table View Cell error when Identifier is set

Tags: uitableview, xcode4.2, storyboard, identifier

In xCode 4.2, when I set the `identifier` property to my prototype cell in storyboard, I get the error `Uncategorized - Compilation Failed` when I try to build my project.

I'm not sure what all information you'll need, so I'll put what I think is relevant...

First, I have a view controller that I've set a table view inside of in Storyboard.  In the table view, I've placed a prototype cell.  In the prototype cell, I've placed a UIImageView and 3 labels.

I have a custom cell class called `DOR_SearchCustomCell` .h and .m files.  Here is the .h file:

```
@interface DOR_SearchCustomCell : UITableViewCell {

    __weak IBOutlet UIImageView *cellImage;
    __weak IBOutlet UILabel *cellTitle;
    __weak IBOutlet UILabel *cellText;
    __weak IBOutlet UILabel *cellDistance;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *cellImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cellTitle;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cellText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cellDistance;

@end
```

And the .m file:

```
#import "DOR_SearchCustomCell.h"

@implementation DOR_SearchCustomCell

@synthesize cellImage;
@synthesize cellTitle;
@synthesize cellText;
@synthesize cellDistance;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

My prototype cell has this class set as it's custom class, the style set to Custom, the identifier set to `specialsCell`, and the image and labels are tied to the variables in the class file.

The class that controls the view controller is `DOR_SearchViewController` with .h and .m files.  The .h file is:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <sqlite3.h>
#import "DOR_RestaurantClass.h"
#import "DOR_SearchCustomCell.h"

@class Reachability;

@interface DOR_SearchViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate, NSURLProtocolClient, NSXMLParserDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

    __weak IBOutlet UITableView *tblView;

    NSMutableData *receivedData;
    NSXMLParser* parser;
    NSString *currentElement;
    NSMutableString *currentElementValue;
    NSMutableArray *listItems;
    NSMutableArray *listOfIds;
    NSMutableArray *listOfNames;
    NSMutableArray *listOfDistances;
    NSMutableArray *listOfImages;
    NSMutableArray *listOfAddresses;
    NSMutableArray *listOfAddresses2;
    NSMutableArray *listOfAddresses3;
    NSMutableArray *listOfDescriptions;
    NSMutableArray *listOfPhones;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tblView;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *receivedData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSXMLParser *parser;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *currentElement;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *currentElementValue;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *listItems;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *listOfIds;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *listOfNames;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *listOfDistances;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *listOfImages;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *listOfAddresses;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *listOfAddresses2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *listOfAddresses3;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *listOfDescriptions;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *listOfPhones;

- (void)get_table_data;

@end
```

And the .m file:

```
#import "DOR_SearchViewController.h"
#import "Reachability.h"

@implementation DOR_SearchViewController

@synthesize tblView;

@synthesize receivedData;
@synthesize parser;
@synthesize currentElement;
@synthesize currentElementValue;
@synthesize listItems;
@synthesize listOfIds;
@synthesize listOfNames;
@synthesize listOfDistances;
@synthesize listOfImages;
@synthesize listOfAddresses;
@synthesize listOfAddresses2;
@synthesize listOfAddresses3;
@synthesize listOfDescriptions;
@synthesize listOfPhones;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (![[self loadSettings:@"view"] isEqualToString: @""]){
        [sortButton setTitle:[self loadSettings:@"view"] forState: (UIControlState)UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    listItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    listOfIds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    listOfNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    listOfDistances = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    listOfImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    listOfAddresses = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    listOfAddresses2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    listOfAddresses3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    listOfDescriptions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    listOfPhones = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self get_table_data];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)get_table_data {
    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.url.com/"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if (theConnection) {
        //NSLog (@"At connection");
        receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {  
    if(parser){
        parser = nil;
    }

    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: receivedData];
    [parser setDelegate: self];
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities: YES];
    [parser parse];

    [tblView reloadData];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
    //NSLog (@"At parser");
    currentElement = elementName;

    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"restaurant_details"]) {
        if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"total_results"]) {
            //NSLog(@"Element: %@", currentElement);
        }else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"restaurant"]) {
            restaurantObj = [[DOR_RestaurantClass alloc]init];
        }
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    //NSLog (@"At parser2");
    if(!currentElementValue)
        currentElementValue=[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    else
        [currentElementValue appendString:string];

    //NSLog(@"Name to be saved in Array :- %@",currentElement);

    //NSLog(@"the parser just found this text in a tag:%@",currentElementValue);
    if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"name"]) {
        restaurantObj.name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",currentElementValue];
        [listOfNames addObject:currentElementValue];
        //NSLog(@"At Name | Array = %@", listOfNames);
    }else{
        restaurantObj.name=@"";
    }
    if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"distance_from_current_location"]) {
        restaurantObj.distance=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",currentElementValue];
        [listOfDistances addObject:string];
    }else{
        restaurantObj.distance=@"";
    }
    if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"restaurant_id"]) {
        restaurantObj.restId=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",currentElementValue];
        [listOfIds addObject:string];
    }else{
        restaurantObj.restId=@"";
    }
    if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"address"]) {
        NSArray *stringArray = [currentElementValue componentsSeparatedByString:@" | "];
        restaurantObj.address=[stringArray objectAtIndex:0];
        restaurantObj.address2=[stringArray objectAtIndex:1];
        restaurantObj.address3=[stringArray objectAtIndex:2];
        [listOfAddresses addObject:[stringArray objectAtIndex:0]];
        [listOfAddresses2 addObject:[stringArray objectAtIndex:1]];
        [listOfAddresses3 addObject:[stringArray objectAtIndex:2]];
    }else{
        restaurantObj.address=@"";
        restaurantObj.address2=@"";
        restaurantObj.address3=@"";
    }
    if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"phone_number"]) {
        restaurantObj.phone=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",currentElementValue];
        [listOfPhones addObject:string];
    }else{
        restaurantObj.phone=@"";
    }
    if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"description"]) {
        restaurantObj.description=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",currentElementValue];
        [listOfDescriptions addObject:string];
    }else{
        restaurantObj.description=@"";
    }
    if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"image_url"]) {
        restaurantObj.image=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",currentElementValue];
        [listOfImages addObject:string];
    }else{
        restaurantObj.image=@"";
    }
    if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"restaurant_type"]) {
        //restaurantObj.Name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",currentElementValue];
    }else{
        //restaurantObj.name=@"";
    }
    restaurantObj.expires=@"";

    //NSLog (@"ID Array: %@", restaurantObj);
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser*)parser didEndElement:(NSString*)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString*)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString*)qualifiedName {
    //NSLog(@"Current element in End Element Category:- %@",currentElement);
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"restaurant"]) {
        //NSLog(@"Array: %@", restaurantObj);
        //[listItems addObject:restaurantObj];
    }else{
        currentElementValue=nil;
    }

}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog (@"Table Cells: %d",[listOfIds count]);
    return [listOfIds count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellID = @"specialsCell";

    DOR_SearchCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[DOR_SearchCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    }

    NSLog (@"Name: %@", [listOfNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

    cell.cellTitle.text = [listOfNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.cellText.text = [listOfDescriptions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.cellDistance.text = [listOfDistances objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [listOfNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

If I do not put in the cell identifier name in the story board, my project compiles and I do get the default cell style (set when `cell == nil`), which is why I added the `cell.textLabel.text` part at the bottom for testing purposes.

I really don't know too much about programming for the iPhone yet.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  All the tutorials I found did not seem to fit my project (having the table view within a view controller), and did not work when I tried to implement them.  Thanks for all responses.  Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your UIImageView & UILabel outlets originating from your prototype cell.

A prototype cell is not an actual cell; it serves as a blueprint for the real instances. Storyboard is not happy when you place UIImageViews inside this blueprint cell **AND THEN** bind them to your class via outlets. You are basically trying to connect something abstract to something concrete. At that point, storyboard fails and comes up with this unfriendly build error.

More details in this thread: [What does the "Couldn't compile connection:" error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236621/what-does-the-couldnt-compile-connection-error-mean)

Comment: Awesome, I will change this and try it again, then let you know how it works.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I read your question again and you seem to be using custom cells. In that case, there shouldn't be any problems with the outlet connections. In any case, take a look at the build log to see what is actually causing this error. Look at this thread to see how to open the build log: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488931/how-do-you-show-xcodes-build-log-trying-to-verify-if-iphone-distribution-buil