# How to export a build log from Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I am trying to submit a build log to Apple to diagnose a problem but I can't find it. Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Build log? Do you mean console log?

Comment: This is the email, per Apple: "Thank you for contacting Apple Developer Technical Support (DTS). In order fot us to assist you on this, please provide your Xcode build log."

Comment: [this answer will help you i think][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488931/how-do-you-show-xcodes-build-log-trying-to-verify-if-iphone-distribution-buil

Comment: I have read that post, I don't know how to bring that window up in XCode 4.6.3...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the steps as per the this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488931/how-do-you-show-xcodes-build-log-trying-to-verify-if-iphone-distribution-buil)

You may not get "`Open this latest results as transcript text file`" in Xcode 4.6.3 - You may have to use "`Copy transcripts for shown results(....) as text`" and further open a text edit, paste, save & send it to apple.

Update:

**Step-1 (click on the show log navigator on left navigator):** [image]

**Step-2**(Select the build) [image]

**Step-3** (Right click on the row)[image]

Comment: I would follow those steps if XCode 4.6.3 had those windows. I can't recreate that view, so I can't currently follow them.

Comment: Updated with steps as screen shots.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way, which can be useful if your build log is huge and Xcode has problems copying it to the clipboard (I've had one case where the log was 290 MB, don't ask why :) is to build the target from the console with xcodebuild and simply redirect the standard and error outputs into a text file, just like this:

```
xcodebuild -project yourproject.xcodeproj -scheme YourBuildScheme -arch arm64 -sdk iphoneos > build-log.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: is it possible to export messages from the navigator? Build time interests (in case of successful and failed build).

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 15 there's an `Export` button next to the search bar. You can then choose where to save the log.

[image: Export Button]