# C++ standard Library/IBM CPLEX Include array not found ?

Tags: c++, xcode, include, cplex, std

I am using xCode with cplex (following this tutorial http://www.leandro-coelho.com/how-to-configure-ibm-cplex-with-apple-xcode/) when I change c++ standard library to libstdc++ (GNU c++ standard library) I am no longer able to use arrays (include  says not found) when I switch back libc++ (LLVM standard library with c++ 11 support) include  works fine but not cplex.

[Screenshot of Xcode configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTJXR.png)

thank you for your help !

Comment: I'm not an xCode user.  Is there a way you can show us the exact compiler options that are being used?  For example, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488931/how-do-you-show-xcodes-build-log-trying-to-verify-if-iphone-distribution-buil) SO question suggests that they might be in the build log....

Comment: Also, this is a shot in the dark, but did you define `IL_STD` as described [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014972014&ps=25)?